# Prevent positional record from being serialized by XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I have simple C#9 [positional record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#positional-syntax-for-property-definition) with an empty constructor (in addition to primary one):

```
public record FiscalTag(int Code, string Value, List<FiscalTag> ChildTags)
{
    public FiscalTag() : this(default, default, default) { }
}
```

How can I prevent it from being serialized by XmlSerializer?
Records have [EqualityContract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/records#equality-members) (a compiler-genereated vitrual readonly property). This property creates problems in our serialization unit tests. So I need to disable serialization completely.

**More info about our unit test problem:**
In our unit tests we gather all AutoProperties with:

```
var autoProps = Type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly
| BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
.Where(property => property.CanRead 
&& property.GetGetMethod(true).IsDefined(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false).ToList();
```

If we find any readonly AutoProperty or virtual AutoProperty in that list - we throw an exception (they are not supported by XmlSerializer).

Unlike ordinary AutoProperties (where CompilerGeneratedAttribute attribute is applied to getter and setter), **EqualityContract** property itself has CompilerGeneratedAttribute attribute applied. This property is not serialized - so it can be safely excluded from our list:

```
var autoProps = Type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly
| BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
.Where(property => property.CanRead 
&& property.GetGetMethod(true).IsDefined(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), false)
&& !property.IsDefined(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute)).ToList();
```

Comment: then... don't include that in your serialization model?

Comment: "problems in our serialization unit tests". But its ok in production code? We need more details here to understand. Behavior shouldn't change in production code vs. unit tests or you are doing very specific unexpected stuff you should tell about.

Comment: I've added more info about our unit test problem. Looks like I've found the way to exclude **EqualityContract** - it doesn't break our unit-test anymore.

Comment: Do you have a specific XML format you need to apply or any XML will do it? If the latter, then [this](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.CoreLibraries?tab=readme-ov-file#xml-serialization) XML serializer can be a solution (disclaimer: written by me). It supports several `System.ComponentModel` attributes so to ignore a property you can simply apply the `DesignerSerializationVisibilityAttribute` with `Hidden` value.

Answer (score 0):

To intentionally *break* xml serialization, you could implement `IXmlSerializable`:

```cs
public record FiscalTag(int Code, string Value, List<FiscalTag> ChildTags) : IXmlSerializable
{
    public FiscalTag() : this(default, default!, default!) { }

    const string NotSerializable = "suitable message here";

    XmlSchema? IXmlSerializable.GetSchema() => throw new NotSupportedException(NotSerializable);

    void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader) => throw new NotSupportedException(NotSerializable);

    void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) => throw new NotSupportedException(NotSerializable);
}
```

This will at least give you a suitable message at runtime.